# How do I explain this "....not....,(comma) but" sentence

Tags: phrase-structure

[image: text image]

In my reading I saw a sentence that can be seen here. But I dont understand the structure.
....not..., but....

Is it correlative conjunction or something else?
Also there is comma. But in "not... but..." correlative conjuction structure comma sould not be.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You are meant to understand it as "It is not a language, but [it is] a system...".

Answer (score 1):

The comma breaks the sentence, but is not *required*. The grammar rules that you read are general guidance – native speakers don't work from a rule book, but from accepted idiom.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/but) shows this use of

> **but**
> used to introduce an added statement, usually something that is different from what you have said before:
>
> *This is not caused by evil, but by simple ignorance.*
> *She's not a painter but a writer.*

The first example uses a comma, the second does not.